# Regarding REST API

Tags: rest

I'm new to `REST APIs` and trying to understand the basics of them. So lets begin by saying that I have created a simple CMS web application using `PHP` (You create an user, you post an entry and assign some categories maybe, etc...).

That being said, if I wanted to create a `mobile app` that would do the same, I'll have to create some `PHP` functions in order to send data as `JSON` or `XML` and also in order to process a `POST` or `PUT` request.

is a `REST API` the collection of those functions I'd use to handle the mobile app `POST`, `PUT` and `GET` request using `JSON` or `XML` as the data format?  if not, can I get an example, not a definition, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question,yes, the REST API is a collection of those functions for any client you wish to expose it to for creating an user, posting an entry etc. The accepted data format is something you decide for your API. It may be JSON, XML or even both.

**Some examples:**

http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/
http://peter.neish.net/building-a-mobile-app-backend-using-mongodb-and-slim-a-php-rest-framework/